# Recursively render element inside element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

So this is how my react loop looks like:

```
{Object.entries(mmValue.message.users).map(
  ([userKey, userValue]) => (
     <div className={"item"}>
        <img src={userValue.picture} />
      </div>
  )
)}
```

Expected HTML is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-6967-200-rcsktwfqdpnhqloymmncxehvylehbalw.jpeg"/>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/73429-image/Steve-Jobs-documentary-hits-theaters-and-video-on-demand-today.jpg"/>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://cdn.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Elon_Musk_LED_Lit_Wide-200x200.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I get this result using loop in React

Here is example in codepen:

https://codepen.io/ehteshamkafeel/pen/OywvQM

Comment: how is `mmValue.message.users` look like?

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky array of user photos. not nested

Comment: `mmValue.message.users.map(
  (img, index) => (
     <div key={index} className={"item"}>
        <img src={img} />
      </div>
  ))`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky are you sure that it generates nested divs like this?

Comment: oh, i see now.  give me a minute, i will write an answer

Comment: add the code as an answer. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
const imgs = [
    'img1.jpg',
    'img2.jpg',
    'img3.jpg'
];

const Items = ({i = 0}) => (<div className="item"><img src={imgs[i]}/>{i<imgs.length-1?(<Items i={i+1}/>):null}</div>);
return (
    <div className="container">
        <Items/>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .map() and can create a separate  using this function for each of the images you have. Check the example below.

```
const images = [
    'https://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-t-6967-200-rcsktwfqdpnhqloymmncxehvylehbalw.jpeg',
    'image src of another image',
    'image src of another image'
]

const imgList = () => {
  const renderList = images.map((img, i) => {
    return <div key={i}> <img src={imgs[i]}/> </div>;
  });
  return <div className="item">{renderList}</div>
```